# Performance problem about showing images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, uiimageview

My problem is i have 50 images each is 157X157 pixels and take 25kb.They are connected to a slider and when the user slides the slider they change 0 to 100. It works but my problem is iphone 3g and 3gs is very slow its hard to see the images and sometimes it stuck for a second to show the next image. I use UIImageview to show the images.How can i do it better so the phone that before retina display can show them without stucking? Thanks for answers and your time.

edit: All pictures is in the file they are not taking from url.

Comment: Show some code - how are you loading and displaying the images -do they each have their own UIImageView, have you cached an array of 50 UIImages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preload them when your app launches.   Sending each of them a `-size` message should be enough to force them to load.

Comment: i resize all of them so they should be load oke i ll try thanks for your time

Comment: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Smiley_00048.png"] size]; is it enough for application did finish lauching with options?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can preload a lowRez version of your pictures ( like 78px )
when the slider move, you display the lowRez, and when it's stop, you swap to original picture.

Answer (score 0):

convert them to the size they will be drawn at (don't rescale them on the fly).

ps: a sample would help a lot